# react-router-dom v6 useHistory location.pathname

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

Since in react-router-dom `useHistory` is no longer supported, I am looking for an equivalent to use `history.location.pathname`

Comment: use this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63471931/using-history-with-react-router-dom-v6

Comment: TL;DR Use [useNavigate](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/api#usenavigate). For other changes see the [v5 migration guide](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/upgrading/v5).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You have to use [`useLocation` ¹](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/getting-started/tutorial#custom-behavior), [²](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/getting-started/concepts#locations) which returns a location object that contains the `pathname` and other information about the URL:

```
const location = useLocation();

console.log(location)
// {
//   pathname: "/invoices",
//   search: "?filter=sa",
//   hash: "",
//   state: null,
//   key: "ae4cz2j"
// }
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for since useNavigate don't returns that location object. Thanks a lot.