# Route router: add route when using history.push

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am in my react app and I want to go from `https://example.com/route1` to `https://example.com/route1/route1.1` using history.push.

I remember that using `history.push(.)` allows me to go back one route, but what is the cleanest way of going from `/route1` to `/route1/route1.1` using history.push?

edit: this is a simplified route example, in my application there can be more subroutes

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63471931/using-history-with-react-router-dom-v6 maybe this could help you

Comment: So.... `history.push("/route1/route1.1")`? What have you tried? What isn't working as you expect? Is there an issue navigating? Can you add your code to the question? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example Does the RRDv5 [nesting demo](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/example/nesting) help clear it up for you?

Comment: Like I put in the edit, the routes aren't always this simple, sometimes there are more than 4 levels of subroutes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding this as a possible answer, but still open for a more direct way of doing it with just history:

I used the useRouteMatch hook to get the present URL and then added the new route to that url.

```
import { Box, Typography, Button } from '@mui/material';
import { useHistory, useRouteMatch } from 'react-router';

export const ProposalListItem = ({
  proposal: {
    name,
    proposed_asset: { type },
    notes,
  },
}) => {
    const history = useHistory();
    const { url } = useRouteMatch();

  return (
    <Box border='1px solid black' p={2} mt={3} display='flex'>
      <Box>
          <Button onClick={() => history.push(`${url}/test`)} variant='outlined'>More info</Button>
      </Box>
    </Box>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 1):

The latest documentations suggest that you should use `useNavigate` hook or the `<Navigate />` component for navigating.

Reference: https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/api#navigation

If you are using react-router v5, and you want to navigate to a relative path, then you need to construct the new path by getting the current path via `useLocation`.
Here's the location object spec: https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/location

```
const location = useLocation()
const history = useHistory()

const navigate = () => history.push(`${location.pathname}${NEW_PATH_RELATIVE_TO_CURRENT_LOCATION}`)
```

You can also do a replace instead of push by using `history.replace` instead of `history.push`.

Checkout https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/history for complete list of operations available over history object.

Comment: This is only if a user is using `react-router-dom` v6. The API changed significantly from v5. It looks like OP/question is using RRDv5.

Comment: I'm still using V5

Comment: I hear ya! I've added steps for v5.